# Google Places APi photo

Tags: php, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to render an image using php for my website that will dynamically display images straight from the Google Places API (Reference https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos?hl=en)
The image source looks like the following example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=API_KEY
```

If you visit this URL via your browser it will render an image and this is no longer the URL you see.

My issue is that when viewing the page source, this is exactly the image source URL you see which is bad because my key is then publicized. What is the proper way to render images while keeping my key private? I have searched the API and the web for this but to no avail. I did see some tricks using file_get_contents and file_put_contents but my web host does not allow that. Finally, saving the images is against the api rules so that is not an option.

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may send a HEAD-request to the particular URL and extract the content of the `Location`-header:

```
<?php

  $context  = stream_context_create(array('http' =>array('method'=>'HEAD')));
  $fp = fopen('desiredPlacesApiImgUrl', 'rb', false, $context);
  $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

  if(isset($meta['wrapper_data'])){
    $location=preg_grep('@^\s*Location:@',$meta['wrapper_data']);

    if(count($location)){
       $imgUrl=trim(preg_replace('@^Location:@i','',reset($location)));
      die($imgUrl);//the desired img-url
    }

  }
  fclose($fp);

?>
```

But when `file_get_contents` isn't allowed on your server I'm afraid `fopen` also isn't allowed for external URLs.

Another option: use the Maps-Javascript-API, request the place and the response should contain the desired URL (without using any key).

---

Demo:

```js
function loadPlacePhotos() {
  var photos = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-place]'),
    service = new google.maps.places
    .PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
  for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; ++i) {
    (function(photo) {
      service.getDetails({
        placeId: photo.getAttribute('data-place')
      }, function(r) {
        if (r.photos.length) {
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(photo, 'click', function() {
            photo.setAttribute('src', r.photos[0].getUrl({
              maxHeight: 100
            }));
            photo.style.visibility = 'visible';
            if (r.photos.length > 1) {
              r.photos.push(r.photos.shift());
              photo.setAttribute('title', 'click to see next photo');
              photo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            } else {
              google.maps.event.clearListeners(photo, 'click');
            }
          });
          google.maps.event.trigger(photo, 'click');
        }
      });


    }(photos[i]));
  }
}
```

```css
body::before {
        content: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/powered-by-google-on-white2.png);
      }
      img[data-place] {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
      }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Google: Mountain View
    <img data-place="ChIJj61dQgK6j4AR4GeTYWZsKWw" />
  </li>
  <li>
    Google: Sydney
    <img data-place="ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4" />
  </li>
  <li>
    Google: Berlin
    <img data-place="ChIJReW1rcRRqEcRaY3CuKBdqZE" />
  </li>
</ul>
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&callback=loadPlacePhotos"></script>
```

The demo uses a custom attribute for images `data-place` which will be assigned to a `placeId` of a particular place. It parses these images, requests the photos and displays them(when there ar more than 1 photo the user can switch between the photos by clicking on the image )

---

However, it must not be a problem when your key is visible, set the allowed referers for your (browser)-key and you can use the key without a risk on your own domain.

Comment: fopen: You were correct, could not use fopen either. Great thought, however. Your recommendation to use JavaScript works perfectly. I will have to find a way to modify it so the images change on mouseover with a time interval, but this definitely serves my purpose - thank you! Finally, while it is ok that my key is visible in my explained scenario, machines with an ip address that is not registered with my API Key would not display the image at all but a placeholder (literally all visitors). Even I myself am affected due to my dynamic IP. Thank you again for your time and thoroughness, solved.

Comment: I've fixed it(added the defer-attribute to the maps-API)

Comment: Thank you for this. One last question, as I am not JS savvy. How can I make it so that instead of having to click the image tags to see the next photo, I can hover my mouse over it and after every x seconds it loops to the next one? I got as far as replacing "click" with "mouseover" but would like a timer to kickoff and change the image while the mouse is still hovering over it. Thank you in advance.